# Can Lettuce be used for mobile automation.

Tags: python, ui-automation, lettuce

I know there is lettuce_webdriver where i can integrate and execute web apps. But, Is mobile (android and iOS) automation is possible using lettuce? If yes, Pls share the links/tutorials?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.